# React - several stored accounts in one client

Tags: reactjs, account

I'm looking for some information about a problem that I never thought about, and that I can't find much on the internet (or I'm looking wrong).

Here it is, for a dashboard project in my company, I need to be able to set up a system to store one account per client, or I just have to click on the account in question to connect, like twitter, google or instagram for example.

After the person has added his account, it appears in a list that can switch whenever he wants. Only I don't really see how to set this up, storing the login information in the localStorage? or the jwt token? I confess that I can't find a correct and secure solution as it should be, that's why I'd like to know if some people would have already done that, or if I can be oriented on an interesting solution?
Thanks a lot!

(Sorry for my english, i'm french and it's not perfect ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use localStorage. LocalStorage is not secure at all and can easily be hijacked through any js code running. If you need to store sensitive information, you should always use a server side session.

When a user logs into your website, create a session identifier for them and store it in a cryptographically signed cookie. If you're using a web framework, look up “how to create a user session using cookies” and follow that guide.

Make sure that whatever cookie library your web framework uses is setting the httpOnly cookie flag. This flag makes it impossible for a browser to read any cookies, which is required in order to safely use server-side sessions with cookies. Read Jeff Atwood's article for more information. He's the man.

Make sure that your cookie library also sets the SameSite=strict cookie flag (to prevent CSRF attacks), as well as the secure=true flag (to ensure cookies can only be set over an encrypted connection).

Each time a user makes a request to your site, use their session ID (extracted from the cookie they send to you) to retrieve their account details from either a database or a cache (depending on how large your website is)

Once you have the user's account info pulled up and verified, feel free to pull any associated sensitive data along with it

Comment: Thank you for responding. The problem is that we have jwt authentication because our entire app runs under API. So is it better to store the jwt token in the cookie? Another problem, here we would seek to be able to store several token of indeterminate duration, in order to be able to easily switch account...

Comment: @Minos I recommend reading this article https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04 and especially the comments. There's a ton of discussion in those comments about the same issue. I hope this helps to clarify stuff

Comment: We'll store the token some other way, probably in cookies. But what always bothers us is how to store several for account switch without going through the login...

Comment: I think the approach is not ideal. Better to have one token shared across all accounts?

Comment: I'm not sure... Each account will have unique usernames/passwords and they can be used in several places at the same time, but the association of accounts won't necessarily be the same (it's quite complicated to explain...)